# Check / find in url if the there're any word of the array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys i have make this :

```
$("a").click(function() {
    var x = $(this).attr("href");

    var Site_dont_go = ["#", "youtube.com"];

    var check = jQuery.inArray(x, Site_dont_go);
    if(check > -1 ){

    } else {

        window.open('goto.php?url='+x);
        return false;
    }

});
```

it is work fine but if the url was like (youtube.com/other_code) it's not checked

Please help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to search within the URL itself to find the domain. You can do this with `indexOf`:

```
$("a").click(function() {
    var x = $(this).attr("href");
    var Site_dont_go = ["#", "youtube.com"];
    var validUrl = true;
    $.each(Site_dont_go, function(i, item) {
        if (x.indexOf(item) != -1) {
            validUrl = false;
        }
    });

    if (!validUrl) {
        window.open('goto.php?url=' + x);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Note that searching for `#` is not a great idea though, as you will end up excluding any URL with a fragment, eg. `http://www.microsoft.com/#foo`

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I set href of all  the links <a> without the links in ' Site_don't_go ' !?